# using Android.mk I cannot call Java_ functions from MainActivity.java, but using CMakeLists.txt works ok

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android.mk

1. I have created a simple JNI project,
2. I create test.cpp file and inside it I created `Java_com_etc_function1()`
3. I used `CMakeLists.txt` to create test.so shared library
4. I loaded the shared library in MainActivity using 
   `System.LoadLibrary('test');`
5. I called `public native void function1()` successfully.
6. when I run `nm.exe -D test.so` , I can confim `Java_com_etc_function1()` exists.

Everything is ok until I decided to replace the `CMakeLists.txt` file with `Android.mk` file.

When ever I change my app gardle file to point to :

```
ndkBuild {
     path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
}
```

instead of CMakeLists.txt, 
  my project stills build the test.so library, and when I run nm.exe -D test.so
I also can confirm that `Java_com_etc_function1()` exists in it, and am still able to load the library in MainActivity.java , **but the problem is :** I am not able to call:  `public native void function1()` , its in red color, error: **cannot find matching JNI function Java_com_etc_function1()** , and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> -> choose create function - Nothing happens.

This is my Android.mk file below,

Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk file:

```
APP_OPTM := release
APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

I think I am missing 1 more step to do to be able to call this function from MainActivity.java , but I still can't figure out. Please if you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to add Class Name in this `Java_com_etc_function1()`

Comment: `function1()` is your native method and `com.etc` is your package, you need  to add Java's class name that contain your method.

Comment: take a look of this tutorial http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

Comment: Try this with a new project from scratch, or clean up the project and re-import. When you switch from CMake to ndk-build, some AS caches may not be correctly updated.